# Find particular table in Neo4j on the basis of property

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use regular expressions in a cypher `WHERE` clause. I would like to match tables (nodes) which contains specific property.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.Text =~ '*'
RETURN n;
```

I want to find all nodes which contains "UName" property.

So please suggest what should I put in where clause.

Answer (score 3):

To get all nodes that have the `UName` property you can use the [keys()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) function. This way:

```
MATCH(n)
WHERE 'UName' in keys(n)
```

Also, remember that Neo4j has no table concept. The data is stored as nodes and relationships, both with properties. Take a look in this [Property Graph Model intro](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-database/).

Comment: I think you meant `in keys(n)`, as `properties(n)` would return a map

Comment: @InverseFalcon Oh right! My mistake! Corrected! Thanks again! :)